# Regex: Replacing only one occurrence

Tags: python, regex, matching

I'm trying to replace only one instance of a specific word in a string using regex, where the word that needs to be substituted appears at least twice. For instance I have the following:

`The NOUN is ADJECTIVE and is completely different from the NOUN.`

so far I have:

```
content = 'The NOUN is ADJECTIVE and is completely different from the NOUN.'   

noun = input('Enter a noun: ')
adj = input('Enter an adjective: ')
noun_1 = input('Enter another noun: ')

names_regex_noun = re.compile(r'NOUN')
content = names_regex_noun.sub(noun, content)
names_regex_adj = re.compile(r'ADJECTIVE')
content = names_regex_adj.sub(adj, content)
names_regex_noun_1 = re.compile(r'NOUN')
content = names_regex_noun_1.sub(noun_1, content) 
print(content)
```

The problem that I'm having is that when using `names_regex_noun.sub(noun, content)` it is replacing both instances of `NOUN` in `content`. I would like to only replace the first and leave the second instance of `NOUN` unaffected so that it could be substituted by `noun_1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x="abc abc abc"
print re.sub(r"abc\s*","",x,count=1)
```

Output:`abc abc`

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)` 

use `count=1`
```

Answer (score 4):

For simple expressions like that, you can just use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) with a specified `count`:

```
>>> content = 'The NOUN is ADJECTIVE and is completely different from the NOUN.'
>>> noun = 'bird'
>>> content.replace('NOUN', noun, 1)
'The bird is ADJECTIVE and is completely different from the NOUN.'
```